# How to scroll when using for each loop?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

My Piece of code...

When index is more than 10, The page has the horizontal scroll bar..

Without scrolling, when attempt to find the element it throws no such element found exception is thrown.

Is it possible for,  @ final catch if element is not found, then scroll and then go to start again..

But i doubt that if that element is really not present it might be an infinite loop.. please suggest some idea how to resolve this?

```
public string[] GetHeaders(NgWebDriver driver, Table table, string[] IndexMapping) 
        {
            string[] columnHeaders = new string[IndexMapping.Length];
            int index = 0;
            try
            {
                foreach (var column in IndexMapping)
                {

                    try
                    {               
                        columnHeaders[index] = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#columntable" + table.TableID + " > div:nth-child(" + column + ") > div > div:nth-child(1) > span")).Text;   
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        try
                        {                                                   
                            columnHeaders[index] = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#columntable" + table.TableID + " > div:nth-child(" + column + ") > div > div:nth-child(1)")).Text;   

                        }
                        catch 
                        {
                            columnHeaders[index] = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='columntablegridRecords']/div[" + column + "]/div/div")).Text;
                        }
                    }                    
                    index++;
                }
            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException nsee) { throw new NoSuchElementException("Element not found", nse); }
            return columnHeaders;
        }
```